# What do these prophetic lines in The Hidden Oracle mean?

Tags: meaning, rick-riordan, the-trials-of-apollo

So there are 2 lines in The Hidden Oracle

> The fall of the Sun
>   The final verse

Well obviously, the fall of the Sun refers to Apollo becoming mortal. but what about the final verse?

A theory;

- It refers to the lack of oracles. There would be no prophecies because of Apollo.

But that doesn't make sense, as even before the Grove of Dodona was tamed, it gave prophetic lines. Something about Indiana and seemingly random stuff.

Comment: I fully endorse your analysis.  Great insight!  (I haven't read the books, but without Apollo, there is no prophecy, at least in the Greek model.)  Possibly a clue is in a double meaning?  Could "fall of the Sun" be a reference to the end of the world? i.e. in Norse mythology, the sun is swallowed up by Fenrir during Ragnarok.  Apollo is linked to wolves, see [Apollo: wolf-god](https://earthandstarryheaven.com/2016/06/15/apollo-wolf/)

Answer (score 1):

## We don't know.

The meaning hasn't been revealed in any of Rick Riordan's books so far. This might be explained in *The Dark Prophecy* (the second book in the series); we'll have to wait and see.

**Speculation part**

It refers to the last trial of the gods and their allies - first they had the titans, then Gaea, and now the triumvirate. After this, they will either be defeated or won't have any troubles for now.

**Speculation 2**

Remember, this is Python speaking. He saying *The fall of the sun* (i.e, Apollo), *the final verse* - like, this is the end, it's over, you're going to die now, mwahahaha. He's just being a scary evil dude.